# Another guessing game in Python, with a little difference

Tags: python, python-3.4

Before writing this question, I looked for something similar in the forum, but did not find any. So here is my version of the guessing game. I want the user to guess a number from 0 to 10 that the computer has "thought". But I want to calculate the difference of the numbers and show whether the user is close or not to figuring out the correct number.
My code is as follows:

```
import math
import random

intnum  = random.randrange(0,11)
print(intnum)

print ("The computer generated a random number from 0 to 10! Can you guess it?")
guess = 0
while guess != intnum:
    guess = int(input ("Pick a number!!: "))
    num = abs(guess-intnum)
    print (num)
    if (num==0):
        print ("Congrats! The answer is %s" % (guess))
        break
    elif (num>0 or num<=2):
        print ("You are less than 2 away. Keep going!")
    elif (num>2 or num<=5):
        print ("You are more than 2 away. Try again!")
    elif (num>5):
        print ("You are more than 5 away!! Try again.")
```

I print the computers number and the difference, to find my bugs easily. There is a logical error that I cannot solve. If the computer generates a number 9, and I guess a number 1, the difference is 9-1=8. But the program, prints "You are less than 2 away", which is incorrect. What am I doing wrong? I would like to use this in a larger version with more numbers but for starters I scaled it down a bit to find the correct logic and syntax.

Comment: `num>0 or num<=2` evaluates to True when num is eight, because eight is greater than zero.

Comment: Try `and` rather than `or`

Comment: doctorlove I Tried using and instead of or, it didn't work. As it turns out, I needed to write only a num<=2 since I already have the condition above.

Comment: Kevin that was the answer to my false logic. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

This block needs rewriting from

```
if (num==0):
    print ("Congrats! The answer is %s" % (guess))
    break
elif (num>0 or num<=2):
    print ("You are less than 2 away. Keep going!")
elif (num>2 or num<=5):
    print ("You are more than 2 away. Try again!")
elif (num>5):
    print ("You are more than 5 away!! Try again.")
```

to

```
if (num==0):
    print ("Congrats! The answer is %s" % (guess))
    break
elif (num>0 and num<=2):
    print ("You are less than 2 away. Keep going!")
elif (num>2 and num<=5):
    print ("You are more than 2 away. Try again!")
elif (num>5):
    print ("You are more than 5 away!! Try again.")
```

I understand what you're trying to do with the "or"s in your initial code block, but the computer will think differently, and in this case, "and" is your friend.

Comment: In the second conditional, `num` is implicitly greater than 0, and likewise in the third `num` is implicitly greater than 2. The fourth and last conditional can be replaced with just `else`, but you're right to point out that the logical error lies in the use of `or` instead of `and`.

Answer (score 1):

The right statement is:

```
elif (num<=2):
    print ("You are less than 2 away. Keep going!")
```

Answer (score -1):

The condition you are using does not do what you want.

You need to check if a number lies in an interval. To do so, you need to ensure that the number is greater that the lower bound **and** lower than the upper bound

You need to change the `or` to `and` in your conditions